# Propuesta: Test rápido sobre los buenos hábitos de la plataforma para nuevos usuarios

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Como nuevo usuario de la plataforma (como muchos otros), cometí errores en la formulación de mis respuestas así como en la navegación del sitio en mis primeras incursiones.

Navegando por la plataforma, me he dado cuenta que años atrás, quizás había menos usuarios pero estos estaban más especializados y en cierto modo, se respetaban mas las reglas o recomendaciones de la plataforma y se compartía mas entre los usuarios el objetivo de esta. (*Mi opinión totalmente subjetiva y personal*).

Como ya he comentado, muchos nuevos usuarios cometemos errores por no leer los documentos que están a nuestro alcance sobre como manejarse en el sitio, últimamente he estado pensando en ello y creo que esta propuesta quizás podría mejorar un poco el sitio.

Se trataría de dos test rápidos sobre como responder y como preguntar. Si el nuevo usuario quiere preguntar o responder primero debería aprobar este breve test y una vez aprobado quizás se podría otorgar alguna medalla o algún punto de reputación que en mi opinión seria una buena manera de motivar e integrar al nuevo usuario a la vez que este aprende las reglas básicas de la plataforma.

Me refiero a preguntas del estilo:

1.- ¿Qué debo hacer para realizar una buena pregunta?

- a) Explicar de la manera más breve y clara posible mi consulta.
- b) Mostrar mis intentos, fallos y resultados en la pregunta.
- c) a y b son ciertas.

> **Aclarar** que no seria un test de evaluación, en el que si el usuario falla las respuestas no pueda realizar las acciones, sino que mas bien es una manera dinámica de aprender el funcionamiento de la red, en la que el usuario podría repetir el test, ver los errores, etc...

¿Creéis que seria positivo o negativo? ¿Por que razón?

Comment: Supongamos que le hacemos un par de preguntas.. y si falla? no lo dejamos preguntar? y si no falla? demostraria realemente algo? y se la hacemos solo antes de la primera pregunta? Suena interesante.. pero recuerda que somos una red.. y algo asi deberia funcionar para toda la red...

Comment: La idea no seria un aprobado y suspenso, sino que el usuario puede repetir el test tantas veces como lo necesite. Se trata de que al menos el usuario lea de alguna manera la forma correcta de hacer las cosas. Luego esta claro que las podra aplicar o no, pero como he dicho, desde el punto de vista de un nuevo usuario, normalmente entramos y no nos detenemos a leer la forma correcta de hacer las cosas y por eso creo que es positiva la propuesta. Principalmente creo que seria positivo para los objetivos de toda la red, que es compartir conocimientos pero de una forma ordenada y accesible.

Comment: Yo he visto ideas similares en SOen y siempre son descartados, y conociendo el objetivo actual de la empresa pienso que va en contra de sus nuevas políticas por lo que nunca será aceptado ni implementado ya que una consecuencia(no se si deseada) sera reducir el número de preguntas( y probablemente el numero de nuevos usuarios)

Comment: y probablemente los ingresos publicitarios entiendo. Gracias por tu comentario.

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que lo que propones bien valdría la pena aplicarlo un poquito diferente, en lugar de plantearlo como "evaluación", plantearlo como encuesta voluntaria permanente y a los que "reprueben" sugerirles que editen su pregunta / respuesta.

Cabe señalar que esto sería reiterativo pues ya se dice como se debe proceder en varias partes del sitio. Por otro lado, siempre habrá gente que va a hacer "lo que se le dé la gana" por mas que se le sugiera, solicite, proponga, invite, ruegue, implore, ordene que haga las cosas de cierta forma.

---

La nueva página Preguntar ya tiene algo más o menos así.

El usuario que por primera vez intentará publicar una pregunta se le recibe con una ventana emergente indicando lo que se espera, luego el usuario escribe un borrador de la pregunta, luego le da click un botón y se le muestra una evaluación de si el título, cuerpo o etiquetas de la pregunta "pasaron la prueba", si es así puede publicar la pregunta y en caso contrario se le señala que es lo que tiene que corregir.

Luego con base en ciertas métricas la pregunta podría pasar a "revisión humana".

Si bien las repuestas no tienen algo como la nueva página Preguntar, estas también podrían pasar a "revisión humana".

La premisas del sitio que se señalan a los nuevos visitantes son:

1. Cualquiera puede preguntar
2. Cualquiera puede responder
3. Se vota a favor de las mejores respuestas, y éstas suben a los primeros puestos

Relacionado

- [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344513/the-new-ask-page-is-now-live-on-the-network)